# PHPSpreadsheet - Where is "PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing"

Tags: phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I am really **mad** at **PHPSpreadsheet**, and why the functions are not named as in **PHPExcel**, or why in documentation doesn't mention something about "**PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing**", where can I find it in **PHPSpreadsheet**?.

In **PHPExcel** I have this:

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Logo');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Logo');
$objDrawing->setPath(Sys::$_R["images"].'logo_med.png');
$objDrawing->setHeight(110);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

Now, how can I *achieve* that?

Comment: You are comparing at two different libraries, See: The [Migration file](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/fff363078078753a2092b7e945514642309bccdc/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Helper/Migrator.php#L170) or The [Drawing object](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/develop/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Drawing.php) file itself or the [Documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#add-a-drawing-to-a-worksheet)

Comment: I have tried to run the Migration exec, but all classnames got wrong

Comment: "class \PHPOffice\Worksheets\Drawing{}" That's a Syntax Error.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? the `::class` constant was added in PHP 5.5

Comment: PHP FPM 7......

Comment: We apologise for trying to convert PHPExcel into a modern library fit for 21st century PHP rather than simply restricting ourselves to 20th century coding practises, and for assuming that users were living in the 21st century

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the answer for me was find every class to "match" PHPExcel-PHPSpreadsheet..

```
require_once 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet as spreadsheet; // instead PHPExcel
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx as xlsx; // Instead PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing as drawing; // Instead PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment as alignment; // Instead PHPExcel_Style_Alignment
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill as fill; // Instead PHPExcel_Style_Fill
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color as color_; //Instead PHPExcel_Style_Color
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup as pagesetup; // Instead PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory as io_factory; // Instead PHPExcel_IOFactory
```

Then my code:

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Logo');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Logo');
$objDrawing->setPath(Sys::$_R["images"].'logo_med.png');
$objDrawing->setHeight(110);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

Is now:

```
$objPHPExcel = new spreadsheet();
...
$objDrawing = new drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Logo');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Logo');
$objDrawing->setPath(Sys::$_R["images"].'logo_med.png');
$objDrawing->setHeight(110);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
...
$objWriter = io_factory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Xlsx');
$objWriter->save("route/to/save/file.xlsx");
```

The trick was, that have to find function names in every PHPExcel_* class that match with PHPSpreadsheet files, and that's how I achieved this. Take care about https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/migration-from-PHPExcel/#migration-from-phpexcel , that comparing table.

I hope this will be useful.